# Getting an error when trying to move code from the Playground to its own file

Tags: swift

Hi guys I'm having issues trying to get this little playground to run, I mocked this up in the Playground which works fine but I'm having issues trying to get it to run in its own `swift` file

```
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
let url = URL(string: "http://reddit.com/r/globaloffensive/new")!

let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
    (data, response, error) in

    if error != nil {
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
    } else {
        do {
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any] {
                dump(json)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }
    }
})
task.resume()
```

I'm mainly trying to figure out how to make API calls, but when I run this in its own file and run

`swift run test.swift` I get

```
test.swift:1:14: error: use of unresolved identifier 'URLSessionConfiguration'
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.swift:2:15: error: use of unresolved identifier 'URLSession'
let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
              ^~~~~~~~~~
test.swift:3:11: error: use of unresolved identifier 'URL'
let url = URL(string: "http://reddit.com/r/globaloffensive/new")!
          ^~~
```

Any information would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the Foundation framework:

```
import Foundation
```